# asp.net error CS0103: The name 'WebMail' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an application with a simple contact form.

The view to send the email:

```
@{
    try
    {
        WebMail.SmtpServer = "";
        WebMail.SmtpPort = 587;
        WebMail.UserName = "";
        WebMail.Password = "";
        WebMail.From = "";

        WebMail.Send("", "New contact",
            Model.Name + " <br> " + Model.Email + " <br> " + Model.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        @:<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry! We couldn't send the email to confirm you RSVP.</div>
    }
}
```

When I fill the form and send it shows me this error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'WebMail' does not exist in the current context
```

How can I fix this error?

I have the same code in other project and it works. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afzaal's answer is close. But your code sample and tags make it seem like you're using a razor view. To add a namespace to the view use `@using System.Web.Helpers` at the top of the view.

Or if you're going to use it on more than one view, add the following to the web.config file inside the Views folder under the `<namespaces>` tag:

```
<add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
```

Comment: is defined both, @using System.Web.Helpers and the namespace in web.config in Views is there

Comment: @bramalho Are you missing an assembly reference? In the solution explorer, under references of your project, is `System.Web.Helpers` in there?

Comment: yes. it was missing, I copy the dll and xml from other project to bin folder, manually. Btw, theres another way to add this when is missing?

Comment: @bramalho Not that I know of. Since any assembly can add classes to a namespace, Visual Studio doesn't know what assembly the class you're looking for could be in. It is possible for visual studio to propose `using` statements when the project reference already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
using System.Web.Helpers;
```

in the top of your Code Page, where you're having other `using` statements. After this your code would have the `WebMail` in the document.

You can only use the Objects and Classes once you include them in your code directoy. You can either directly refer to the as

```
System.Web.Helpers.WebMail.Send();
```

Or you can use this method

```
using System.Web.Helpers;
// then in the code 
WebMail.Send();
```

Both ways you can use the code. But, not just by referencing. Because a single Name reference would force the compiler to look for `WebMail` and there won't be such Class in your project.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webmail(v=vs.111).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webmail%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)